# How to show that lg n! = Theta(n lg n) without using Stirling Formula

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I have to show that

```
lg n! = Theta(n lg n)
```

But I have to do this without using the Stirling Formula. I know how to do this with the Stirling formula but I cannot do it without it, can anyone give me a hint on how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "sandwich" the factorial between two expressions, which have the same asymptotic growth.

For example:

```
(n/2)^(n/2) < n! < n^n
```

and then

```
log((n/2)^(n/2)) < log(n!) < log(n^n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the properties of the logarithm:

1. `log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)`
2. `log(x^y) = y log(x)`

Alongside the approximation:

[image]

You should see some nice terms coming up which you can then apply a bound to.